# Clickstream measures at different granularities

Tags: ssas, granularity, measures

This is possibly a simple problem which I have yet to overcome.

Consider a cube based on clickstream data.

First, I have a fact table based on page views. That is One Row per page view on a site. Measures includes [Views], [Visits], [Bounce Rate] etc.

Secondly I have a measure group based on Leads. Measures include [Leads], [Revenue], [Margi]n etc.

One page can create multiple leads, therefore a one to many relationship exists. OFF of this Leads Fact I also have a Leads Dimension which describe the lead. An example attribute  may be [Quality] = Good / Bad.

Now when browsing the cube I might want to see the number of [Views] or [visits] against the Lead Attribute, [Quality]. The problem in a one [View] to many [Leads] is that the [Views] are incorrectly multiplied for each lead each created.

e.g. One [View] created 3 [Leads]. [views] by [quality] = 3

I want Views by Quality to be DIVIDED and = 0.33 or, ideally, still 1.
*"**1** View Created 2 bad and 1 Good Lead"*

Would anyone have any ideas on how to solve this ?

THANK YOU !!!

Comment: Do you have some kind of unique identifier for a view or visit?  I'm hoping yes since you have a fact at the page view granularity but you are still somehow calculating visits.

Comment: I do have a unique identifier, yes. The problem is that leads are at a lower granularity. I'm considering joining the facts into a single fact table which is at lead level, but still contains measures for single page visits with not leads, and call this fact_activity or something.

Comment: I think I like your idea of a single fact table at the lead level.  Then you can just have a dimension for Lead and do distinctcounts on the measures for views and visits based upon their IDs.